# d3js : register same event (drag) for same element twice

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm using d3js to work with svg animation. I want to import an svg file into my svg canvas. The imported file may contain listener -d3.behavior.drag- for dragging, I want to register new dragging listener. The problem is that when I import the file, my listener is removed and only the one within the file remains. I tried using namespaces but it does not work. Maybe I misunderstood how it should be done.
Any help please!!

**EDIT**

I have in the file to be imported:

```
var dragListener = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag.act", function(d,i) {
        console.log("dargging " + i);
    })
    .on("dragstart.act", function(d,i) {
        console.log("drag start " + i);
    })
    .on("dragend.act", function(d,i) {
        console.log("drag end " + i);
        // some code ....
    });

d3.selectAll(".draggable").call(dragListener);
```

And in the svg canvas I have

```
var dragevt = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag.svg", function(d,i) {
        console.log("parent dragging");
    })
    .on("dragstart.svg", function(d,i) {
        console.log("parent drag start");
    })
    .on("dragend.svg", function(d,i) {
        console.log("parent drag end");
    });

svgParent.call(dragevt);
```

Elements with class "draggable" don't output "parent drag ..."

Comment: Post some code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear. I have a good understanding of drag behavior in d3 but not yet up to speed on canvas. If you can include a working code snippet (or fiddle) I would probably be able to figure it out and solve your problem ...

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I have 
  `d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();`
 inside the "dragstart.act".

Comment: The snippet does not reflect that...